# Do Django Template Processors Mess with URLs?

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

In Django, I am trying to render a url to a template.  However, this url is rendered differently depending on how it is called.

In the view:

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri()
print(url) # returns http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/
raise Exception(url) # returns //localhost:8000/path/
print(url[0]) # returns h
raise Exception(url[0]) # returns h
```

In the template:

```
{{ url }} <!-- returns //localhost:8000/path/ -->
```

I feel like I am going crazy here.  Do Django's template context processors contain a regular expression that specifically checks for urls and messes with them?

Comment: No, likely it is just an object that has a different `str` and `repr` method.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered that, but str(url) and repr(url) both exhibit the same discrepancy between printing and rendering in a template.

Comment: Also, raise Exception("h" + url[1:]) returns //localhost:8000/path/, but url[1:] returns ttp://127.0.0.1:8000/path/

Comment: I think this has something to do with Gulp actually, because when I disable Gulp and use the original development port instead of the Gulp port, then I get a consistent result.